# writing the same result for the duplicated values of a column

Tags: bash

I'm really new to bash. I have a list of domains in a .txt file (`URLs.txt`). I also want to have a .csv file which consists of 3 columns separated by `,` (`myFile.csv`). My code reads each line of `URLs.txt` (each domain), finds its IP address and then inserts them into `myFile.csv` (domain in the first column, its IP in the 2nd column.

```
Name, IP
ex1.com, 10.20.30.40
ex2.com, 20.30.40.30 
ex3.com, 10.45.60.20 
ex4.com, 10.20.30.40
```

Here is my code:

```
echo "Name,IP" > myFile.csv   # let's overwrite, not appending
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ipValue=                            # initialize the value
    while IFS= read -r ip; do
        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            ipValue+="${ip}-"           # append the results with "-"
        fi
    done < <(dig +short "$line")        # assuming the result has multi-line
    ipValue=${ipValue%-}                # remove trailing "-" if any
    if [[ -n $ipValue ]]; then
                # if the IP is not empty
        echo "$line,$ipValue" >> myFile.csv
    fi
done < URLs.txt
```

I want to add another column to `myFile.csv` for keeping open ports of each IP. So output would be like this:

```
Name, IP, Port
ex1.com, 10.20.30.40, 21/tcp 
ex2.com, 20.30.40.30, 20/tcp 
ex3.com, 10.45.60.20, 33/tcp 
ex4.com, 10.20.30.40, 21/tcp
```

I want to use Nmap to do this. After I choose an IP address from the 2nd column of `myFile.csv` and find its open ports using Nmap, I want to write the Nmap result to the corresponding cell of the 3rd column.

Also, if there is another similar IP in the 2nd column I want to write the Nmap result for that line too. I mean I don't want to run Nmap again for the duplicated IP. For example, in my example, there are two "10.20.30.40" in the 2nd column. I want to use Nmap just once and for the 1st "10.20.30.40" (and write the result for the 2nd "10.20.30.40" as well, Nmap should not be run for the duplicated IP).

For this to happen, I changed the first line of my code to this:

```
echo "Name,IP,Port" > myFile.csv
```

and also here is the Nmap code to find the open ports:

```
    nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 $ipValue -oN out.txt
    port=$(grep '^[0-9]' out.txt | tr '\n' '*' | sed 's/*$//')
```

but I don't know what to do next and how to apply these changes to my code.

I updated my code to something like this:

```
echo "Name,IP" > myFile.csv   # let's overwrite, not appending
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ipValue=                            # initialize the value
    while IFS= read -r ip; do
        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            ipValue+="${ip}-"           # append the results with "-"
        fi
    done < <(dig +short "$line")        # assuming the result has multi-line
    ipValue=${ipValue%-}                # remove trailing "-" if any
    if [[ -n $ipValue ]]; then
                # if the IP is not empty
        nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 $ipValue -oN out.txt
        port=$(grep '^[0-9]' out.txt | tr '\n' '*' | sed 's/*$//')
        echo "$line,$ipValue,$port" >> myFile.csv
    fi
done < URLs.txt
```

but this way, Nmap was used for finding the open ports of the duplicated IPs too, but I didn't want this. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try sticking the code to get the open ports somewhere into your loop? What happened?

Comment: Yes, I put it inside the loop before "echo "$line,$ipValue" >> myFile.csv", but it used Nmap to find the open ports for duplicated IPs too, but I don't want this.

Comment: So, if two domains resolve to the same IP address, you wouldn't want to run `nmap` again? That's not mentioned in the question at all. As it stands, all you have to do is add your two lines and modify the output to `echo "$line,$ipValue,$port" >> myFile.csv`. There are a few stylistic problems, but they're not related to the actual question. And maybe there's a more efficient approach overall, but I don't know `dig` and `nmap` well enough to judge.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, but I mentioned this. I would update my post to clarify the problem.

Comment: You're right! My bad.

Comment: If `dig +short` returns multiple IP addresses, you're pasting them together with hyphens between them, is that intentional? The output would have `amazon.com,176.32.98.166-176.32.103.205-205.251.242.103`

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, that's intentional.

Comment: Isn't `nmap` going to break if you feed it multiple hyphen-separated IP addresses?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, I should do something for that too :( if I find out the solutions for the ones without hyphens, maybe later I can solve it too... maybe I find IP from methods other that "dig" or something.

Comment: This might be easier to do in a language other than bash.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, but I need to do it in bash!

Comment: If a domain has multiple IP addresses, do you want to do the ports scan for each IP address, or just once?

Comment: @BenjaminW. If it is possible, I want to do the port scan for each IP address, but if not, just once and the first IP.

Comment: And what would the output look like for a line with multiple IP addresses? `amazon.com,176.32.98.166-176.32.103.205,80/tcp-80/tcp`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your script that roughly does what you want:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# cache maps from IP addresses to open ports
declare -A cache

getports() {
    local ip=$1
    nmap -v -Pn -p 1-100 "$ip" -oG - \
        | awk -F '\t' '
            /Ports:/ {
                n = split($2, a, /,? /)
                printf "%s", a[2]
                for (i = 3; i <= n; ++i)
                    printf ":%s", a[i]
            }
        '
}

{
    echo 'Name,IP,Port'

    while IFS= read -r url; do
        # Read filtered dig output into array
        readarray -t ips < <(dig +short "$url" | grep -E '^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$')

        # Build array of open ports
        unset ports
        for ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
            ports+=("${cache["$ip"]:=$(getports "$ip")}")
        done

        # Output
        printf '%s,%s,%s\n' \
            "$url" \
            "$(IFS='-'; echo "${ips[*]}")" \
            "$(IFS='-'; echo "${ports[*]}")"
    done < URLs.txt
} > myFile.csv
```

The `readarray` line reads the filtered output from `dig` into an array of IP addresses; if that array has length zero, the rest of the loop is skipped.

Then, for each elements in the `ips` array, we get the ports. To avoid calling `nmap` if we've seen the IP address before, we use the `${parameter:=word}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): if `${cache["$ip"]}` is non-empty, use it, otherwise call the `getports` function and store the output in the `cache` associative array.

`getports` is called for IP addresses we haven't seen before; I've used `-oG` ("[grepable output](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html)") to make parsing easier. The awk command filters for lines containing `Ports:`, which look something like

```
Host: 52.94.225.242 ()  Ports: 80/open/tcp//http///     Ignored State: closed (99)
```

with tab separated fields. We then split the second field on the regular expression `/,? /` (an optional comma followed by a blank) and store all but the first field of the resulting array, colon separated.

Finally, we print the line of CSV data; if `ips` or `ports` contain more than one element, we want to join the elements with `-`, which is achieved by setting `IFS` in the command substitution and then printing the arrays with `[*]`.

The initial `echo` and the loop are grouped within curly braces so output redirection has to happen just once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete & clear explanation. I will try the code and tell you the result. By the way, is it possible to save the output of `dig +short "$url" | grep -E '^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$'` into a variable like `ipvalue` and pass `ipvalue` to `readarray -t ips`?

Comment: @Pablo You could do that with something like `output=$(dig ... | grep ...)`, and then `readarray -t ips <<< "$output"` (a "here-string")

Comment: The fact is that in my Nmap command I write the result to `output.txt`. This file contains multiple lines. The lines I'm looking for start with numbers and for example is like this: `21/tcp open   ftp`. I used this command `grep '^[0-9]' out.txt | tr '\n' '-' | sed 's/-$//'` but I don't know how to rewrite it using `awk`. Also the one I've written gives `"21/tcp open   ftp"`, how can I extract only `"21/tcp"`?

Comment: @Pablo Do you *need* it in a file? Do you read elsewhere from it? Also, the ports fields is apparently by far the most complicated output field of `nmap`. How robust does your solution have to be? If it has to cater to any possible value, it's probably a pretty big task.

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfect, except for the scenarios in which more than one open port is found and the 2nd field is like this: `Ports: 21/open/tcp/ftp, 80/open/tcp//http///`. In this case, it returns only the first found port, I mean: `21/open/tcp/ftp,`.

Comment: @pablo Oh, that should be fixable in the awk bit. Do you have an example of a domain with multiple open ports?

Comment: yes. For example: http://scanme.nmap.org/. I splited the second field using `:`. It almost gave the desired output.

Comment: @Pablo I've modified the awk function to report all open ports, colon separated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209928/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-pablo).