# identify duplicated values in a column

Tags: bash

As an attempt to simplify my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728792/writing-the-same-result-for-the-duplicated-values-of-a-column), Imagine I have a .csv file with 2 columns (cul1 and cul2):

```
echo "cul1,cul2" > myFile.csv
```

The content of the myFile.csv at first:

```
cul1, cul2
Alice, 
Bob,  
John,  
Alice,
Bob,
Alex,
```

is it possible to insert a specific value such as "100" in the 2nd column of the duplicated values of cul1? Something like this:

```
cul1, cul2
Alice, 100
Bob, 200 
John,  
Alice, 100
Bob, 200
Alex,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you need by reading the lines into a a couple arrays with `awk` and then looping over the stored lines in the `END` rule and assigning a suffix value for each array element that appears more than once (increment the suffix value by `100` each time)

The two arrays required in the normal rule section are an `order[]` array that stores the order of the lines so they can be output in the same order (`awk` arrays are associative) and then a `seen[]` array that keeps a count of the number of times the first column text is seen. In the `END` section you assign the suffix to an array indexed by the values seen more than once so you can output, e.g. `100` for each time `"Alice,"` is seen and `200` for `"Bob,"`, etc...

The `awk` script would look like:

```
awk '{ order[++n] = NF>1 ? $0 : $1; seen[$1]++ }
END {
    sfx=100
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if (seen[order[i]] > 1) {
            order[i] in val || val[order[i]]=sfx
            print order[i]" "val[order[i]]+0
            sfx+=100
        }
        else
            print order[i]
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can simply copy and middle-mouse-paste the script in an xterm in the directory containing your input file. With your input above in `file`, you would have:

```
$ awk '{ order[++n] = NF>1 ? $0 : $1; seen[$1]++ }
> END {
>     sfx=100
>     for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
>         if (seen[order[i]] > 1) {
>             order[i] in val || val[order[i]]=sfx
>             print order[i]" "val[order[i]]+0
>             sfx+=100
>         }
>         else
>             print order[i]
> }' file
cul1, cul2
Alice, 100
Bob, 200
John,
Alice, 100
Bob, 200
Alex,
```

Which provides the output you requested. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This way, when the 2nd "Alice" is met by the code, it will be ignored? I mean if a field in the 2nd column contains a value (which means its first column is previously seen), it will not be overwritten?

Comment: No, all that is happening above is the suffix value is being *appended* to each of the names that are seen more than once. The `val[]` array is used to associate which suffix value goes with which name. Look at the output above, each time `"Alice,"` is seen, `100` is appended as the 2nd column, for `"Bob,"`, `200` is appended. Both instances of either are still there.